# Yup conditional validation in nested object with typescript

Tags: typescript, yup

I have the following yup validation schema written in typescript:

```
export const billingAddressStepSchema = yup.object().shape<Partial<BillingAddressStepData>>({
  sameAsContractHolder: yup.bool(),
  address: yup.
    string()
    .when("sameAsContractHolder",
      {
        is: false,
        then: yup.string().required("Campo obbligatorio"),
      }),
  addressNumber: yup.
    string()
    .when("sameAsContractHolder",
      {
        is: false,
        then: yup.string().required("Campo obbligatorio"),
      }),
  zipCode: yup.
    string()
    .when("sameAsContractHolder",
      {
        is: false,
        then: yup.string().required("Campo obbligatorio"),
      }),
  city: yup.object().when("sameAsContractHolder", {
    is: true,
    then: yup.object().shape<LookupItem>({
      id: yup.string(),
      description: yup.string(),
      //@ts-ignore
      type: yup.string(),
    }),
    otherwise: yup.object().shape<LookupItem>({
      id: yup.string().required("campo obbligatorio"),
      description: yup.string().required("campo obbligatorio"),
      //@ts-ignore
      type: yup.string().required("campo obbligatorio"),
    })

  })
});
```

In the form I have to validate with this schema, there is a CheckBox "Same as legal address" that, when is checked, the fields *address*, *addressNumber*, *zipCode*, *city* must not be required.

The above validation schema works perfectly, my question, in fact, is more related to typescript: for the city field it gives the following error

[image]

How can I properly write this rule in order to not have that typescript error?

Many thanks in advance